# Minecraft on Cairo Dock Opens Another Instance

Tags: 12.10, minecraft, cairo-dock

So i "installed" Minecraft using this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZIbcWpdSA4 and put it on my cairo dock. However whenever I open it, it opens another instance of the icon. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This is 100% speculation, but my knee-jerk reaction for doesn't work on Ubuntu/Cairo/Unity is software shouldn't use Java.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way to get a .java on cairo to not open a new instance?

Comment: It's probably related to how the cairo and unity docks detect that an app is running (like they find "java" as opposed to "someJavaApp.jar")

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the issue is still there. The solution is simple. Follow these steps.

1. Open the application that creates an additional icon in the dock, minecraft in this case.
2. Make sure if is not hidden behind any other windows since you're going to have to click on it.
3. Right click on the minecraft icon in cairo dock, and select "edit"
4. Expand "Extra Parameters"
5. Click "Grab" button to turn your cursor into crosshairs
6. Click on minecraft **window**. This should put minecraft application class beside the "grab" button and eliminate that duplicate icon right away.
7. Click Apply -> Close

Hope it helps someone.